# How to solve SoapException: Server was unable to process request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I got following error while I was trying to connect to my SQL database with Xamrain.

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''

I have written web service in ASP.Net.
My code is :

```
var objMonoAndroidService = new mywebservice.WebService();
objMonoAndroidService.Insertdate(txt.Text,"1");
```

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user` seems to be quite clear. Provide correct credentials for your database connection.

Comment: but my credential is working fine. With only web services it goes smoothly. But when I called from my Android App. it gives the same error